# Rails: in_place_select set a foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm attempting to use the Super Inplace Controls plugin, which has an in_place_select method.  I have the following models:

```
class Incident < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to              :incident_status
  validates_existence_of  :incident_status
end

class IncidentStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :incidents
end
```

Right now, IncidentStatus is just an ID and a name ('Open' and 'Closed').  In the show view for Incident, I want to allow a user to click on the current status, and change it using a select menu.  So in show.html.erb, I have the following:

```
<p>
    <b>Status:</b>
    <%= in_place_select :incident, :incident_status_id, :choices => @statuses.map { |e| [e.name, e.id] }, :display_text => @status.name %>
</p>
```

This follows the example given in the Super Inplace Controls documentation pretty closely, which is:

```
<%= in_place_select :employee, :manager_id, :choices => Manager.find_all.map { |e| [e.name, e.id] } %>
```

This actually works fine until I click okay to change the field and submit the POST.  I see the Status, then when I click on it brings up a drop down menu with 'Open' and 'Closed'.  When I select 'Closed' and press okay, the form disappears.  The following shows up in the web server console:

```
Processing IncidentsController#set_incident_incident_status_id (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-05-14 10:18:43) [POST]
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"OK", "action"=>"set_incident_incident_status_id", "authenticity_token"=>"eahXrzwJwe+h2Byi1ELWXLy0QNmqF2EEXNw+eAfUJwU=", "id"=>"1", "controller"=>"incidents", "incident"=>{"incident_status_id"=>"1"}}

...snip...

ActionController::UnknownAction (No action responded to set_incident_incident_status_id. Actions: admin?, authenticated?, authorized?, create, destroy, edit, index, new, set_incident_incident_status, set_incident_title, show, and update):
```

So it appears to be looking for a method "set_incident_incident_status_id".  If I define this method in my Incident Controller, it seems to be okay, but I have no idea how to grab the "incident_status_id"=>"1" that was passed in and set it as the foreign key.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it.  I needed to create a method in the Incident Controller.  It looks like this:

```
def set_incident_incident_status_id
  @incident = @customer.incidents.find(params[:id])
  @incident.incident_status = IncidentStatus.find(params[:incident][:incident_status_id])
  @incident.save
end
```

I need to finish it, but that's the gist.